# ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection

Tags: collections, reference, initialization

I am getting "ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection" even after initializing collection to assign a value. Could you please help.  Please find the code below.

```
    create or replace TYPE TYP_GRP_ID  is object (grp_id number);
    create or replace TYPE TAB_GROUP is table of TYP_GRP_ID;

create or replace PACKAGE TEST AS
  PROCEDURE TEST;
 END;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
  PROCEDURE TEST
    IS
     acc_arr           TAB_GROUP;
     BEGIN
         acc_arr.EXTEND;    
         acc_arr := new TAB_GROUP(null);
         acc_arr(acc_arr.LAST).grp_id := 1000;
         dbms_output.put_line(acc_arr(acc_arr.LAST).grp_id);
  END;
END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Mathew

Answer (score 0):

Need to initialize acc_arr, see updated code below

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
  PROCEDURE TEST
    IS
     acc_arr           TAB_GROUP  := TAB_GROUP();
     BEGIN
         acc_arr.EXTEND;    
         -- acc_arr := new TAB_GROUP(null);
         acc_arr(acc_arr.LAST).grp_id := 1000;
         dbms_output.put_line(acc_arr(acc_arr.LAST).grp_id);
  END;
END;
```